# Tensorflow 2.2: Iterator.make_initializer returns None

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run a code written in tensorflow 1.1 using tensorflow 2.2. I already run the `tf_upgrade_v2` which changed most of the unsupported things. However, while creating an iterator

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_function, gen_types, gen_shapes)
train_data = train_data.map(map_func=map_func, num_parallel_calls=self.num_threads)
# Prefetch data
train_data = train_data.prefetch(10)
# create a iterator of the correct shape and type
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.Iterator.from_structure(tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_types(train_data), tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(train_data))
```

and when I initialize it:

```
train_init_op = iter.make_initializer(train_data)
```

The initalization operator `train_init_op` is `None`. and I got the following error when i run `sess.run(train_init_op)`
:

```
File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 958, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1166, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 477, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 263, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

How can I solve this issue?

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution:Ubuntu 18.04
- TensorFlow version: 2.2.0
- Python version: 3.6
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.2 / 7.6
- GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti / 12 Gb

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40588

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I am the one who posted this issue. I'm still working on a small example, because the code is very complicated and big, but meanwhile, if someone had the same issue in the past and can help, it would be great!